# Python Script dont wake Up

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have a script to take screenshots of our garden and after sunset he makes a time lapse from the pictures. I send the script to sleep until the next day, but he hasn't woken up. I can't find the problem. maybe you can help me this Script is running in a Docker on Fedora and Fedora can't run `python3 -u /script >& output &` ... attached my script (sry i am still a beginner)

```
import datetime
from astral import LocationInfo
from astral.sun import sun
from time import sleep
import os
import requests
import pika
import sys


channel_id = '#####'
class pikacord:
    def push_msg(self, msg):
        url = ('amqp://#####')
        params = pika.URLParameters(url)
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='amq.topic', routing_key='discord.msg', 
        properties=pika.BasicProperties(
            headers={'channelId': channel_id}),
            body=(msg))
        connection.close()
        return connection.close

class Sunclock:
    def suntime(self):
        #Locationdata
        l = LocationInfo('City', 'Deutschland', 'Europe/Berlin', ######cords, ######cords)

        #Suncal

        #sunrise
        s = sun(l.observer, date=datetime.date.today())
        sunrise = s["sunrise"]
        self.sunrisetime = sunrise.strftime('%H:%M')


        #sunset
        sunset = s["sunset"]
        self.sunsettime = sunset.strftime('%H:%M')


        #current
        current = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        self.currenttime = current.strftime('%H:%M')
        self.currenttimelong = current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

        #date
        self.date = datetime.date.today()


#init def suntime
sunfloat = Sunclock()
sunfloat.suntime()

try_count = 0
loopi = True
while loopi == True:
    sunfloat = Sunclock()
    sunfloat.suntime()
    get_sunset = sunfloat.sunsettime
    get_sunrise = sunfloat.sunrisetime
    get_current = sunfloat.currenttime
    print (get_sunrise)
    print (get_sunset)
    print (get_current)
    if try_count <=3:
        try:
            if get_current >= get_sunrise and get_current <= get_sunset:
                #take Pictures 
                foldercheck = os.path.isdir('/apps/media')
                if foldercheck == False:
                    os.mkdir('/apps/media')
                    os.mkdir('/apps/motioneye')
                else:
                    print ('Folder exist')

                os.chdir('/apps/media')
                take_pic = 'curl ' "'http://######/picture/3/current/?_username=######&_signature=########'" ' --output `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`snapshot.jpg'
                print (take_pic)
                os.system(take_pic)
                print ('please smile')
                sleep(180)           
            else:
                #make Timelapse
                os.chdir('/apps/media/')
                delete = 'sudo rm /apps/media/*snapshot.jpg'
                move = 'mv *.mp4 /apps/motioneye/Camera3'
                timelapse = 'ffmpeg -r 30 -pattern_type glob -i "*snapshot.jpg" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`timelapse.mp4'
                os.system(timelapse)
                os.system(move)
                os.system(delete)
                #time to sleep 
 Problem--->        while get_sunrise > get_current or get_sunset < get_current:
                    get_sunset = sunfloat.sunsettime
                    get_sunrise = sunfloat.sunrisetime
                    get_current = sunfloat.currenttime
                    sleep(300)
                print ('good morning sun is rising at :' + get_sunrise)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('somthing was wrong:' +str(e))
            try_count += +1
            if try_count ==3:
                broker = pikacord()
                text = ('Greencam abort, to many errors please help:' +str(e))
                print ('abort mission!!!')
                #send abort Massage to Discord
                discord = broker.push_msg(text)
            else:
                sleep(300)
    else:
        loopi = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

The reason as to why your script hasn't "woken up" yet is because you're either misunderstanding how classes work or you've just overlooked a part of your code (I'll assume it's the former as the answer is more informative that way).

A class is made of methods (functions) and attributes (variables). They can be used either directly (statically) or through instances. In your case you're trying to use the class `Sunclock` as an instance named `sunfloat`: `sunfloat = Sunclock()`.

In the next line you run the `suntime` method using `sunfloat` and that sets the attributes: `sunrisetime`, `sunsettime`, `curenttime`, `curenttimelong` and `date`. Afterwards you just assign variables to some of those attributes.

Now, let's go to the root of the problem:

```py
while get_sunrise > get_current or get_sunset < get_current:
    get_sunset = sunfloat.sunsettime
    get_sunrise = sunfloat.sunrisetime
    get_current = sunfloat.currenttime
    sleep(300)
```

What you're doing here is assigning the variables to the same attributes all the time. `sunfloat.sunsettime`, `sunfloat.sunrisetime` and `sunfloat.currenttime` will never change while you're in the loop, they won't get new values out of thin air - their values need to be changed.

## Solution

In order to change the values of the attributes, you'll want to call the `suntime` method again. The method will set all the attributes to the most up-to-date values:

```py
while get_sunrise > get_current or get_sunset < get_current:
    # All the attributes get re-assigned to the most up-to-date values.
    sunfloat.suntime()

    get_current = sunfloat.currenttime
    get_sunset = sunfloat.sunsettime
    get_sunrise = sunfloat.sunrisetime

    sleep(300)
```

Comment: @Virus88 No problem. I just have to inform you that I've edited the solution as the `get_sunset` and `get_sunrise` actually need to be re-assigned as well (previously I said that it may be unnecessary, but it's actually needed).

Comment: Dope answer! Though, you should also make sure that the device that script is run on does not have a skewed clock because that might be another error source. On top, I'd rather not send the python script "to sleep" and rather use something like crontab to periodically invoke the python script so that the script itself can focus on it's sole purpose.